# Is there a way to display new column in Orders html table in Kentico without touching the code?

Tags: kentico

I'm using Kentico MVC v12 with a fresh installation of DancingGoat(MVC) template.

I've modified the "E-commerce" module by adding a new column in the "Order" table.
[image]

I would like to be able to see it on the "Order" module in the list page.
[image]

I see in the "User interface" tab that it uses an "aspx" page.
[image]

In it I see that it calls an "ascx" page that uses a "UniGrid" component and specify the columns directly in a data attribute.
[image]

I don't like the idea to modify this file to display my new column because I see this website as the foundation of my next features, I would like to avoid as much as possible to touch the code of the website template, do you know if there is an other way ?

Maybe I'm missing a configuration somewhere else ?

Thank you by advance !

**Update 06-03-2019:**
I tried the solution of Peter Mogilnitski but it doesn't work :x

I added the column in the data source
[image]

Then I checked the column in widget configuration
[image]

Nothing is displayed
[image]

I debugged the sql query, I don't see my column in the query, is there an other configuration to do somewhere else ?
[image]

**Update 08-03-2019:**

The support of Kentico confirmed that the solution I proposed that was confirmed by @Rui was the right way to do it.

Thank you everyone !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the custom field to appear in the UI, you will have to make change to the ascx page. You will need to make a note to that because you will likely need to update it during upgrade or hotfix (less likely)

Other than adding the data field to Columns, you will also need to add ug:column to the  section

```
<ug:Column Name="SAPID" Source="SAPID" Caption="SAPID" Sort="SAPID" />
```

Comment: That's really sad that they didn't took the time to make it configurable.... So changing the view is inevitable ^^'
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is. This is the widget called **orders**:

1. You need to go to widgets, select **orders** widget and add your column to visible columns
   [image]
2. Now go to store overview:
   Click on properties of latest orders (this is **orders** widget used all over the store) and scroll down to column and make your column checked.
   [image]

Comment: I updated my post with your suggestion, but it doesn't work, it seems that the problem comes from the sql query, is there something else to do so the sql query returns my column ?

Comment: Technically you can put in orders web part, orders widget is based is based on it.

Comment: Check the event log. I did this thing in kentico 8 but it should be the same principle in all subsequent version. Ask support. I might be missing somehting, but I know it should be customizable without touching the code.